# I am unable to get multiple percentage bars working for each file

Tags: php

I am wondering if anyone would be kind enough to assist. This ajax upload works, but it only shows one progress bar and each file loads individually. It shows the progress for the first file and when the first file is uploaded the progress bar resets to zero and then it shows the progress for the next file, and so on until all the files are uploaded.I am unable to get multiple percentage bars working to show the progress for each file as it uploads simultaneously.I would ideally like another progress bar which shows the overall progress of the whole upload but this is not essential.Any assistance you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
   <h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" multiple>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' id="file2"  value='Upload' onclick='uploadFile();'/>
 <br>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
  <h3 id="status"></h3>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
  </form>
<script>
function _(el) {
 return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
// assuming there is a file input with the ID `my-input`...
var files = document.getElementById("file1").files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
 //alert(files[i].name);
 
 //alert(files[i].type);

 alert(files[i].name+" | "+files[i].size+" | "+files[i].type);
 

 
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file1", files[i]);
  




  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php"); 
  //use file_upload_parser.php from above url
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
}
function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0; //wil clear progress bar after successful upload
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
$filename = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

/* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
$location = "upload/".$filename;

/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
  echo 'Success'; 
} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `progressHandler` function you can create new progress bars.
For example:

```
$('{DIV}').append('<progress id="progressBar-{ID}" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>')
```

with:
`{DIV}`: can be a container or anything else
`{ID}`: is the `i` element of files.lenght

then you should compare the "event parameter" if it is already created

Try with that

Comment: Hi Claudio Vega Lagos, Thank you for your help. Most grateful.

I am unsure how to do this. Are you able to advise?